# Exporting Telerik RadGrid data in zip format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to export RadGrid data in zip format. For this, first I'm exporting data in Excel format and then I'm trying to compress it. But the return type for the method  `RadGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()` is `void` so I cannot store this Excel sheet's result in order to pass it as input to `ZipPackage.`

Comment: Can't you create a stream from export method and then use telerik own zip control to grab stream and zip it?

Comment: you are saying that to create stream from ExporttoExcel method but I an unable to create stream from ExporttoExcel method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Radgrid does not have a Zip export method.
What you can do is: export the file in excel and then zip the excel file (or any other type you have exported).
This is how I would do it:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        //column you may like to excluded from the export process
        if (col.UniqueName.Contains("EditCommandColumn") ||
            col.UniqueName.Contains("attachments") ||
            col.UniqueName.Contains("Upload") || col.UniqueName.Contains("Delete_col"))
        {
            col.Display = false;
        }
        else
        {
            col.Display = true;
        }

    }
    foreach (GridFilteringItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem))
        item.Visible = false;
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "YourDesiredFileName";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel(); //this will be exported to the folder Download
    Zip();
}

private void Zip()
{
    //here your method with your preferred library to zip the file exported from the radgrid
    //save it where you need it, rename it as you like it and delete the original excel file
}
```

Comment: I got it Felice but what i'm trying to do is to avoid the middle excel file. If we use RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel(); a pop up will show with options prompting to either open save or cancel. I don't want to save and again read this file to perform zip operations on it. My final output should be zip file there shouldn't be any other intermediate files.

Comment: I understand but this is why I do it by button and not using the embedded features of the radgrid. Nothing pops-up with the above code on my computer and the intermediate file can be deleted at the end of the zip method. Good luck!

Comment: Good idea Felice - although i thought ExportToExcel() does force pop up?

Comment: @TheTiger It doesn't on my version Q3 2013. Thanks

Comment: I never see a save confirmation popup.  In fact, FileName seems to get ignored.  Not sure what I am doing wrong but the ExportToExcel and the others seem to misbehave in a web environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try hooking into the OnGridExporting command and then do something like this

```
   using (FileStream fs = File.Create("path you want to save the file")) {
            Byte[] info = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(e.ExportOutput);
            //save it on the server
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
```

put all of this in a try , catch to watch for file permission problems and file already exists issues.

Comment: Did you actually get the export command (whatever type) to write to a file?  I cannot get it to recognize the filename setting.